# Multiple clickable links in TextView

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add a TextView with the classic `you accept our terms and conditions and privacy polcy` text with web links to the ToS and Privacy Policy but got stuck trying to get the links to work. I am able to create the links but they do nothing when clicked. I have tried many solutions, but none seem to work.

How would you go about making multiple links work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set the correct MovementMethod to make links clickable.

Java

```java
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Kotlin

```
textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Comment: I've tried that, it actually has the opposite effect, it makes the links look like regular text instead and still doesn't make them clickable. :/

Comment: Hmm how do you set the links themselves? With HTML or URLSpan or autolink or ?

Comment: I've tried all three, with and without setting movementMethod.

Comment: Oh... In my rage, I guess I forgot to remove autolinking when trying to setMovementMethod and they were conflicting, making the links unclickable, it works now lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:autoLink="web"` in TextView attributes

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: edit your question with the code you tried then, i show the basic way but i don't really know what you tried